# How to add to a file instead of replacing

Tags: python-3.x

So I would like to be able to have this piece of code add to the Suggestions.txt instead of replacing what there is already in there (ie two lines below the existing content)

```
input1 = input("What is your name?:  ")

input2 = input("What is your suggestion for another issue to be solved:  ")

input3 = input("Do you know how to solve this issue? If not press enter:  ")

input4 = input("What keywords would the user need to use to access the solution? \n Press enter to leave blank:  ")

file = open("Suggestions.txt", "w")

file.write("Name: " +input1 + "\n")

file.write("Suggestion: " +input2 + "\n")

file.write("Solution: " +input3 + "\n")

file.write("Keywords: " +input4 + "\n")

file.close()
```

It is so that multiple people can write what their suggestions are without being overrided by the next people.

I would like it so that it automatically just adds below, and this does not seem to be the case in the other thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.

Comment: Please do tell how your question is different.

Comment: I would like it so that it automatically just adds below, and this does not seem to be the case in the other thread.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is _append_ to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `w` to `a`, ie: `file = open("Suggestions.txt", "a")`